# Chrome, Safari, Firefox outputs XML differently

Tags: xml, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I have this curious question. I was looking at XML files and so I did this twitter search:
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=basketball

The output for Chrome looks like this:
[image]

The output for Firefox looks like this:
[image]

Then, the output for Safari looks like this:
[image]

My question is, what is going on? How can I get the browser to display it in different forms. In other words, if I want to output the `<?xml ...`, how can I do that?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: The XML is exactly the same in all 3 browsers. They each implement their own way of natively displaying it. If you wanT it to look the same on all 3, you're gonna have parse and format it manually. There's no way to force all 3 browsers to display exactly the same unless you do that.

Comment: I suppose I was worried that the browsers append additional html into the page. So, it seems like there's some formatting, etc... going on. If I were to create a web service, I just want the pure xml instead of anything else appended to it.

Comment: If you're creating a web service, this won't matter, since the browser isn't involved. In that case you shouldn't follow my suggestion below; you should just leave it as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the browser to output the `<?xml ...`, send a header that makes the browser think it's a text file, not an XML file:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: If I do this, all browsers will output <?xml if I wanted them to instead of converting it into something else correct?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will render XML with a namespace that they recognize. You can always 'view source' to see the text.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely never want your end-users to look at raw XML anyway. Different browsers decorate raw XML as they wish to make it easier to find stuff in them, but it's still useless as a presentation format.

You should instead link your XML file with an XSLT file to *transform* it into HTML for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is is not just any XML, but an Atom file (Atom is a standard for feeds, like RSS). The browsers (except for chrome) recognize it as such, and format it according to how they format feeds. If you want to view the XML source, just use your browser's View Source function (usually found at the right-click menu).