# XML files having numeric entities doesn't recognize tags

Tags: xml, google-chrome, internet-explorer, difference

I am working on some XML files to parse some data. In one XML file, the content is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataroot>
    <analyst>
        <id>100</id>
        <name>bob</name>
    </analyst>
    <analyst>
        <id>101</id>
        <name>alice</name>
    </analyst>
</dataroot>
```

and in other, the content is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataroot>
    &#60;analyst&#62;
        &#60;id&#62;100&#60;/id&#62;
        &#60;name&#62;bob&#60;/name&#62;
    &#60;/analyst&#62;
    &#60;analyst&#62;
        &#60;id&#62;101&#60;/id&#62;
        &#60;name&#62;alice&#60;/name&#62;
    &#60;/analyst&#62;
</dataroot>
```

In one file there are numeric charecter entities other than the actual charecter.

But when the files are opened in the browser(IE and Chrome), the files seem different.

The first file is showing like -
[image]

The second file is showing like -
[image]

Another thing I checked is if in same file we have both numeric entities and the character itself it shows different things.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataroot>
    <analyst>
        &#60;id&#62;100&#60;/id&#62;
        &#60;name&#62;alice&#60;/name&#62;
    </analyst>
    &#60;analyst&#62;
        &#60;id&#62;101&#60;/id&#62;
        &#60;name&#62;bob&#60;/name&#62;
    &#60;/analyst&#62;
</dataroot>
```

This is shown as

[image]

It recognizes the tags when written normally and can not recognizes if there are numeric entities. Why is it so?
Why those two are shown differently?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome, Safari, Firefox outputs XML differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652915/chrome-safari-firefox-outputs-xml-differently)

Comment: ‘the files seem different’ because they _are_ different, and you've shown how they're different. Can you elaborate on what's unclear to you?

Comment: Why is the first file hierarchically shown in the browser and not the second file? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the files are actually different based on what you show in the question. The first file shows standard XML. The process that created the second file is actually **XML escaping** the *analyst* XML element. This transforms the *analyst* elements to valid text. This [SO question and answer has a good explanation of the reasons for escaping XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents).

The fix is to get the processes that create the XML files to produce consistent unescaped XML.